# Apply quaternion to object3D in three.js

Tags: three.js

I don't have R91 of three.js so I can't use object3D.applyQuaternion. How would I apply a quaternion manually to an object3D?

I've tried

```
var mat= new THREE.Matrix4();
mat.makeRotationFromEuler(new THREE.Euler().setFromQuaternion(q));

//myObject.applyQuaternion(angle); //i don't have this
myObject.applyMatrix(mat);
myObject.updateMatrixWorld();
myObject.updateMatrix();
```

but no avail...

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to `Object3D.applyQuaternion()`:

```
myObject.quaternion.premultiply( q );
```